# Hard Code MVC Route Value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, html.actionlink

I'm trying to utilize the `HTML.ActionLinks` in MVC. I have a route definition like so:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "RestaurantCommon",
    url: "Rest/{siteName}/Admin/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "AdminCommon", action = "Promotions", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Is it possible to use ActionLinks to keep the "Rest" and "Admin" in the folder structure? Below is what I have. It works but doesn't keep the pattern I want (it works because of a default below the one I defined above)

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Burger Star", "Promotions", "AdminCommon", new { siteName="BurgerStar" }, null)</li>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'to keep the Rest and Admin in the folder structure'?

Comment: what you need is RouteLink not ActionLInk refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.routelink(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@RouteLink`

```
@Html.RouteLink("Burger Star", "RestaurantCommon", new { siteName = "BurgerStar" })
```